# Is it possible to kill with XM25 Smoke?

Tags: battlefield-4

M320 Smoke and Flash Bang grenades can kill enemies by direct impact. Is it possible with XM25 Smoke? Does it have impact damage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I was killed by it a couple of times.

And here's a video of this happening: